# Explain GUI annotations in google ccolab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

in colab, I see annotations which render a simple GUI to the right of the cell.  I don't know what this functionality is called.

An example is:

```
#@title howdy
```

If I want to learn more about this, what is it called?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are part of the *forms* syntax; for more information, see https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/forms.ipynb

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea if this is usable in jupyter-lab?